# Prevent an HTTP(s) DoS Attack for Apache

Tags: apache, security, iptables

How to protect the apache webserver against DOS,DDOS .

Note : Already added the rules in iptables.still i am received syn request.

Error :-

```
[root@471283-app2 ~]# dmesg | grep -i syn
megasas: fasync_helper was not called first
possible SYN flooding on port 80. Sending cookies.
possible SYN flooding on port 80. Sending cookies.
possible SYN flooding on port 80. Sending cookies.
possible SYN flooding on port 8080. Sending cookies.
possible SYN flooding on port 25. Sending cookies.




[root@471283-app2 ~]# netstat -n | grep :80 | grep SYN |wc -l
64
```

Iptables Rule

```
[root@471283-app2 ~]# iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 331M packets, 6033G bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
24621 1320K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     173.4.4.4/24       anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh
1314K   77M ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN limit: avg 5/sec burst 5
20245 1196K DDOS_SYNFLOOD  tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 321M packets, 6110G bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain DDOS_SYNFLOOD (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
18656 1108K ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 1/sec burst 3
 1589 87748 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: You need to give us a lot more details. Most importantly -- how precisely is the attack hurting you? Is it maxing out your inbound bandwidth? Your outbound bandwidth? Your RAM? Your connection limit? Or what?

Comment: MY server has 24 GB ram.

Comment: # httpd -l
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  prefork.c
  http_core.c
  mod_so.c

Comment: Apache conf Timeout 100
KeepAlive on
MaxKeepAliveRequests 150
KeepAliveTimeout 5
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       20
MinSpareServers    20
MaxSpareServers   50
ServerLimit      1180
MaxClients      1180
MaxRequestsPerChild  1180
</IfModule>

Comment: Tomcat configuration <Connector  port="8009"
            protocol="AJP/1.3"
            maxThreads="550"
            minSpareThreads="25"
           maxSpareThreads="75"
            acceptCount="200"
            redirectPort="8443"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
            debug="4"
 />

Comment: I have mentioned server configuration above.Currently I am using apache & tomcat with mod_jk connector.

Comment: **How is the attack hurting you?** What are you trying to prevent from happening? (You can't prevent the attack. The attack is someone else's decision. What you can do is stop the attack from hurting you. But to do that, you have to know *how* the attack is hurting you. If it's not, there's probably nothing to do.)

Comment: No problem so far,but I'm keep on getting the Syn flood attack threat   netstat -n | grep :80 | grep SYN |wc -l  =65

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably nothing to do.

You can try methods to make the attacker stop. Perhaps you can identify the IP addresses the attacker is using, file complaints with the attacker's ISP's abuse department, and so on. Perhaps it's a bug or configuration error of some kind and you just need to let the administrators of the source machine(s) know about the problem.

But as far as a technical resolution goes, all you can do is stop the attack from hurting you. And you say it's not hurting you. So what would the point of mitigation or filtering be?